# Auto generate environmental objects in xml file for Omnett++ simulation

Tags: xml, iot, omnet++, inet

I am going to simulate a Smart Home Lighting System using Omnet++. For this, I need to draw the floorplan for the specific building I am simulating my network on. There is a module that does the job for me, however, it has to be rendered with an XML file that contains the positions and the dimensions of the objects (walls mainly) to be drawn.

So, please if anyone knows how to auto generate such and XML file that contains the objects, or it is the only way to go by tediously writing hundreds of lines similar to the following one:

[object position="min 21 15.5 0" orientation="0 0 0" shape="cuboid 10 0.5 2" material="brick" fill-color="203 65 84" opacity="0.8" texture="brick.jpg"/]

Answer (score 0):

This question lacks a few important points:

- What is the source of the floor plan? (you can automatically generate something only from previous data)
- Do you need the walls modeled? I.e. you are using wireless communication where the model behavior is dependent on the attenuation of wireless signals through the wall is properly accounted for? If yes, then you should use the obstacle XML file and indeed you have to create that file. Obviously writing a small program that iterates through your current data and `print` out the corresponding XML elements is very easy.
- If you don't care about wireless propagation and the room plan is only for aesthetics, you can use `@figure` in your NED file and draw on the canvas. See the `CarDemo` sample and `test/anim/canvas` as an example. This will give you scaleable background image that is otherwise unrelated to the model behavior.
- Or you can do it cheaply by creating a PNG image with the plan and putting that into the module background.
- Or you can go and create an OpenSceneGraph 3D model like in `samples/osg-indoor` (OSG can load a lot of 3D formats).